# HTML Website: Check for Location and then Run Code if person is in location

Tags: html, location

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with a short problem. I am trying to have a certain part of my website show only if the user is only in a certain location. For example, only if the User is in Frederick, MD.

If the person is in Frederick, MD, then ... (run code).

How would I write the code to see if the person is in Frederick, MD or not?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: very vague question. You man do this a number of ways, and it depends on how all the fields are stored. How are you identifying if the user is Frederick? Is it a authenticated account? a text-field entry or any other GUI entry? etc.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: I want the website to be able to automatically know where the user is, without the user entering any data. Is there perhaps a way to do this by simply checking the user's IP address? I just need a rough location estimate. Just telling me that he is in the city Frederick is more than enough.

Comment: IP-based geolocation is very prone to errors.